# Dynamic array that contains objects from the class and objects from another class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 2 classes,
in each of those classes I have to create a dynamic array that may contain objects from both of the classes.

for example :
Class - 1 : Mermaid
Class - 2 : GoldFish

each class has a variable int "offspring" and should also have dynamic array with the size of "offspring" , each object in the array may be Mermaid or GoldFish.

the problem is that I don't know which class should inherent and from whom, and if I should use another class as a general container.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AquaticCreature>>` and make `AquaticCreature` an abstract base class of your two classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly this is a textbook example of a simple class hierarchy. Since both Mermaid and Goldfish are types of aquatic beings it makes sense to put all common behavior into a top level AquaticCreature class and then have both Mermaid and Goldfish inherit from it.